# Why are there 2 builds triggered for fast forward pull request?

Tags: github, continuous-integration, travis-ci, pull-request

When pushing to a pull request, there are always two builds going on on [travis-ci](https://travis-ci.org/) displayed in the [github pull request view](https://github.com/Phonations/Joker/pull/319#partial-pull-merging):

- *continuous-integration/travis-ci/pr*
- *continuous-integration/travis-ci/push*

When the branch has been created from master, which stays unmodified by others commits, this triggers two times the same build. Is there a way to do only one build?

Answer (score 0):

That's probably because that PR is from another branch inside the same repo. The `/pr` build is for all PRs which can sometimes be from another repo, while the `/push` part is because this commit was part of this repo.

Comment: Is there a way to disable one or the other?  Is there even a way to see CI jobs that aren't part of a github PR?  The `/push` ones, I guess?